# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getA1'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyldavis

When using `pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare` to visualize an LDA topic model, I encountered the following error message:

```
>>> pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda_model, dtm, vectorizer)
...
---> 12     return dtm.sum(axis=1).getA1()
...
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getA1'
```

Passing `dtm` into `pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare` as a `pd.DataFrame` raises a similar error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'getA1'
```

Why is this error message occurring?

Answer (score 5):

The missing `getA1` method exists only for `numpy.matrix` objects. There is no `numpy.ndarray.getA1` method, nor is there a `pandas.Series.getA1` method.

Casting the document vectors to a `numpy.matrix` resolves the error:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.sklearn
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()

dtm = np.matrix(document_vectors_arr)
pyLDAvis.sklearn.prepare(lda_model, dtm, vectorizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `X = np.matrix(X)` is useful for most situations especially here.
I was also going through the same issue, but on graph data. And my memory could not support my data as a matrix.
I tried scipy sparse array generate by networkx `Y = nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G)`. This `Y` type as `scipy.sparse._arrays.csr_array`. However, fix(X) in `sklearn` does not support this format. `sklearn` only suport `class 'scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix` data.

If you want to get rid of generating a full matrix here, the following code maybe helpful.

```
Y = nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G)
X = csr_matrix(Y)
sc = SpectralClustering(4, affinity='precomputed', n_init=100)
sc.fit(X)
```

here `sc.fit(X)` as an example, it's fits in other `sklearn` data input operation. In this case`sklearn.prepare(lda_model, X, vectorizer)`